# How to fetch info about Closed Projects in Rally using REST API in Java

Tags: java, rally

I am able to fetch Open Projects but unable to get Closed Projects Info from Rally. Response does not have any info about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to query for closed projects via the web services api.  If you know the object id of a closed project you can directly read it, but that's the only way.

```
/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/12345 //closed project ref
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle. That was helpful.